# Merge several different dynamics AX reports in one

Tags: report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I'm investigating if it is possible to send three different Ax 2009 reports to only one output.  We already have [an example of merging multiple invoices using the SalesInvoice report into one output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225296/merge-several-dynamics-ax-reports-in-one), but this is not what we want.  The output would need to be generated by X++ and would contain for example:

- SalesInvoice
- SalesPurchInvoice_RU
- AKT_RU

Any pointers?  An '*It can't be done.*' is an acceptable answer!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done.

Not in AX at least. But you could generate PDF then combine them using an [external program](https://www.google.com/?&q=pdf%20merge%20software) or interface AX with a [.Net library](https://www.google.com/?&q=pdf%20merge%20.Net%20library).

Update: Take a look on [how to merge PDF files](http://dynamicsaxgyan.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/merge-multiple-pdfs-in-to-single-pdf-report-using-x-in-dynamics-ax-2012/)