# hide opening report generated as pdf files on the screen

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have the following problem: I want to merge many reports in 1 report containing all reports.

How can I do to generate only one report and open it in the screen , hiding also the intermediate reports?

Comment: What report or reports are part of this requirement?

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible to merge different reports into one single beast.  The last suggestion I saw was to send them all to a directory in PDF format, merge them with a library, and then open the file generated.  See Jan's answer here for AX 2009 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927182/merge-several-different-dynamics-ax-reports-in-one

Answer (score 0):

Add page breaks after each report. That way only one report would be rendered at a time. Refer the link below:

[**msdn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278.aspx)